# unable to get length of items in .npy file

Tags: python, numpy, object, numpy-ndarray

I have a .npy file [here](https://github.com/SharhadBashar/SC-CAM/blob/master/voc12/cls_labels.npy)

Its just a file with an object that is a list of images and their labels. for example:

```
{
'2007_002760': array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,0., 0., 0.], dtype=float32), 
'2008_004036': array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0.,0., 0., 0.], dtype=float32)
}
```

I want to open the file and get its length, and then possibly add to it or modify it

I am able to open the file, but I cant get the length of items in it.
Heres how i open it:

```
import numpy as np
file = np.load('cls_labels.npy', allow_pickle = True)
print(file.size)
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: It's working just fine for me.  It's claiming to be an array of size 16458x20.  What result are you expecting?

Comment: ah, i put in the wrong link. try now

Comment: NPY file format is intended to represent an array. It doesn't look like you've got an array, or a list of images and their labels. It looks like you've got a dict with string keys and array values.

Comment: If you want to serialize a dict, you should use `pickle`, not `numpy.save` and `numpy.load`.

Answer (score 0):

Your file contains a dictionary wrapped inside a 0-dimensional numpy object.  The magic to extract the actual information is:

```
my_dictionary = file[()]
```

This is a standard dictionary whose keys are strings like `'2008_004036'` and whose values are numpy arrays.

---

Edit: And as mentioned above, you shouldn't be saving dictionaries using `numpy.save()`, you should have been using pickle.  You end up with horrors like `file[()]`.

Comment: `np.save/load` and `pickle` have a lot of interplay.  An array containing `objects` uses their `pickle`, while `save` is the array `pickle` mechanism.  And using the `[()]` (or `item`) to extract an object from a 0d array isn't all that awkward or ugly (IMO).  With `np.load` you don't have to open the file separately (as you would with `pickle`), so in some ways it's actually easier.

Answer (score 0):

here is the correct and easiest way to do it:

```
cls_labels = np.load('cls_labels.npy', allow_pickle = True).item()
```